# setting url in address bar to username in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an website in which, there is registration of users, users can make there profile and lots of stuff like any social networking website.

Now i have made such a thing from scratch that when i or anyone (loggedin as user,having a profile),clicks link to profile of other(i.e friends),a link is set up to such a thing,i.e

**www.Highvay.com?users.php?PID=23**  (means when i open any accounts of my friend or someone else,i usually have above address in my address bar)

usually i use get variable **PID** in **users.php** and then fetch information of that account holder.

```
$PID=$_GET("PID");
// now do all stuff with databse
```

Now what i want is whenever an account opens, one should see www.Highvay.com/mukur

**mukur is username**

For this i tried , changing URL by HTML5's push, but it only changes the url.
Means if i enter "www.Highvay.com/mukur" in address bar manually, page is redirected to elsewhere...

how to implement such a thing ...much like facebook (www.facebook.com/mukur.puri) and twitter (www.twitter.com@7mukur7)

Comment: what was there in giving a negative score to this question, as you showed the duplicate one , my question was more basic.. and more understandable.. think about it!!

Comment: You showed little research effort. This is one of the most asked questions ever. Google "Pretty URLs". Even if you understandably didn't know to google for that yourself, a little bit of poking around existing questions should have let you onto that path pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

the above ur qustion seems to u need to learn more things currently you fetch user information from user id u should create a one field named username 
also u need to learn few things about

- authorization

  - URL  rewriting

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess` file

Check out this link [LIink](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1  
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1  

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```